# How are several test cases in a ROS test node executed?

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a ROS test node (like hztest) does contain more than one test case how are they executed then? (Each with or without a new execution environment? What execution order?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272811/how-are-several-test-cases-in-a-ros-test-node-executed?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within a rostest file, each rostest node is run separately. That is, all of the parameters are set and the normal (test fixture) nodes are started, the first `<test>` node is run until it exits, all of test fixture nodes are stopped, parameters are cleared, and the process repeats for the next test node.

rostest doesn't know much about the test framework within your test node; all it knows is that it produces a junit-style XML file. Therefore, if you are using a framework like gtest or python's unittest framework, all of the tests in a single test node will run in the same environment without restarting nodes (and the state of those nodes and parameters will persist between tests). Similarly, test execution order within your test node will be determined by your test framework.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2021-01-29**:
Where is this documented? I couldn't find an authoritative reference other than your post here :)